# Using Vue JS with Require JS?

Tags: requirejs, vue.js

I installed the following via Bower:

- jQuery 3.1.0
- Vue 1.0.26
- Require.js 2.2.0

But when I load my site, "Vue" is undefined.

I tried `var vue = require('Vue')` and stuff, but it doesn't seem to work.

Vue says it is a AMD module and so is Require.js... What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing Require.js :)

Comment: `var vue = require('Vue')` is not Require.js syntax - it's CommonJS syntax, as used by nodejs on the server side, or build tools like browserify or webpack on the client side. You should read up on how requirejs and AMD modules actually work and weither it is what you want/need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var vue = require('Vue')` won't work by itself. Either you:

1. Change it to the form of `require` that takes a callback:

   ```
   require(['Vue'], function (vue) {
     // code that uses Vue
   });
   ```
2. Or put your `require` call in a `define` call:

   ```
   define(function (require) {
     var vue = require('Vue');
   });
   ```

As Linus Borg [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302260/using-vue-js-with-require-js#comment64024518_38302260), `require` with a single string is CommonJS syntax, which RequireJS supports only if it appears in the callbacks passed to `define`. (See [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar).)