# JQuery not working with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to add a JQuery plugin, owl carousel to a list that rendered using Vuejs.

#### HTML

```
<h4>1. Vuejs rendered items with OWL Carousel (not working)</h4>
<div id="user" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item" v-for="user in users">{{ user.name }}</div>
</div>

<h4>2. Pure HTML with OWL Carousel (working)</h4>
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">Sunny</div>
    <div class="item">Michel</div>
    <div class="item">Daneil</div>
    <div class="item">Sony</div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var list = new Vue({
    el: '#user',
    data: {
        users: []
    },
    methods: {
        listUsers: function() {
            var users = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'John'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Deo'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Anjela'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Samantha'
            }
            ];
            this.$set('users', users);
        },

        installOWLcarousel: function() {
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.listUsers();
        this.installOWLcarousel();
    }
});
```

You can find the entire code from: https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/12/

I seem JQuery is complete it's execution before Vuejs rendered the list. How to avoid that issue? Can I run JQuery after fully rendered the Vuejs for loop items?

Comment: In what order did you place the scripts? Did you install jquery through npm? Did you try adding require('jquery')? Did you try wrapping jquery method in $(document).ready() method? Those are most common issues with vue.js and jquery people face.

Comment: @Pablo, Thanks for your comment. I'm using JQuery CDN, is it fine?

Comment: As long as you load it before your application script tag, it is. I recommend you not usnig cdn unless is a test/practice/ultrasmall project. order should be: jquery > vue.js > application.js

Comment: @Pablo, Its a test project to study Vuejs. The order is correct in my code: jquery > vue.js > application.js

Comment: You should use $(document).ready() to control the rendering then.

Comment: @Pablo, Its not working added $(document).ready() yet. https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/15/

Comment: @Pablo, How to require('jquery'), using RequireJS (requirejs.org)?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302260/using-vue-js-with-require-js

Comment: @Pablo, thanks. I will try that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [Vue.nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) when using a jQuery plugin that needs the DOM to be ready.

From the vue.js documentation:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use
> it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM
> update.

In your case you should use the following implementation of the ready() method:

```
ready: function() {
    this.listUsers();
    Vue.nextTick(function () {
        this.installOWLcarousel();
    }.bind(this))
 }
```

EDIT: For Vue 2 use `mounted()` or `created()`

Comment: `ready()` is depracated in Vue 2 - use `mounted()` or `created()`

Comment: For Vue 3 see https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#nexttick

Comment: @demianh can you please send the right link?

Comment: Yes, the documentation has moved to: https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick

Answer (score 2):

Add ref prop to #user element like this

```
<div id="user" class="owl-carousel" ref="carousel_or_anything">
```

Then in add mounted method to Vue component:

```
...
mounted: function(){
  jQuery(this.$refs.carousel_or_anything).owlCarousel();
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue.nextTick will work in most of the cases, alternatively, you can write your code in the built-in updated() method.

```
updated(){
   // the method called when DOM gets updated
   // write jquery code here 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is really interesting. I think its taking some time to render the DOM and hence carousal is failing. Here I have added a `setTimeout` to add negligible delay and its working:

https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/13/

```
ready: function() {
    this.listUsers();
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.installOWLcarousel();
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: @Pablo - here we can't rely on `jQuery.ready()` because Vuejs's rendering engine is independent of  jQuery.

Comment: You just wrap your jquery elements calls, should be working with that.

Comment: @Pablo - please see this https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/14/ . It uses `$(document).ready()` still gives the same error as that of OP. Do you think we can use it some other way?

Comment: I think yes, as soon I reach home I will tweak the jsfiddle and post the results.

Comment: @vijayP Yes. Its working when using setTimeout() and setInterval(). But can we have any events to check vuejs is fully loaded?

Comment: @Pablo, $( function() ) or $(document).ready() is not working in this case. Its only check the document is on ready. But Vuejs is not complete its rendering before fire the document is ready event.

Comment: @RenjithVK - i think we have only one option to use setTimeout. The other handler is there like `created` but this is also not that much useful. See the fiddle with `created:` handler https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/16/

Comment: @vijayP, Thanks. Its working when add that function in `created`. Thanks but have an issue, It wrapping up the entire `item` in one `item` wrapper div in https://jsfiddle.net/v18yjmuq/16/.

Comment: Yes, I saw that hence it's not that much useful. Even at one of page of it's documentation I seen the use of setTimeout. So I think it's valid to use it here.