# Why am I getting Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: e is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a pretty straightforward component in vue that executes a function from a mounted hook once the component has loaded.

```
methods: {
    pushFolders: function() {
      $.each(this.$store.state.folders.subFolders, function(key, value) {

        this.selected.push(value.uuid)

      }.bind(this));
    },
    checkAll: function(){

      this.isSelectedAll = !this.isSelectedAll;
      this.selectedFolders = [];
      if(this.isSelectedAll){ // Check all
        // this.selectedFolders.push(this.selected[key]);
        this.$store.dispatch('SELECT_FOLDERS',this.selected)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.pushFolders()
  }
```

When I load the route the component is on I get this error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: e is undefined"
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Looks like mounted definition wrong , try this:
mounted ()  {
 this.pushFolders()
}

Comment: Tried this and still get the error

Comment: isn't  mounted () { this.pushFolders() } just the Es5+ way to write exactly what he has?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)
(solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646206/9541423))

Comment: Yeah tried that but it doesn't seem to execute the function at all