# jQuery functions and libraries not works if I include app.js in blade file,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have vue.js component of pusher notification system in my Laravel app and I have to install tinymce for blog posts.
MY tinymce and other jquery functions stops working if i add js/app.js in my main layout blade file. but everything works with normal jquery 3.4.1 public folder link. it is important for me to add app.js because of vue.js components here is my files code

main_layout.blade.php

```
{{--<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>--}}
<script src="{{asset('Assets/bootstrap4/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}" ></script>
<script src="{{asset('node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('node_modules/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.js')}}"></script
<script src="{{asset('Admin/vendor/js-cookie/js.cookie.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('Admin/vendor/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('Admin/vendor/jquery-scroll-lock/dist/jquery-scrollLock.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('plugins/select2/dist/js/select2.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('Admin/js/argon.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-link.collapseLink").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
    });

  })
</script>

@yield('javascript')

</body>
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');


 try {
 window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
 window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

 require('bootstrap');
  } catch (e) {}



  window.axios = require('axios');

  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';



  import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

   window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

   window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     forceTLS: true,
     encrypted: true,
     authEndpoint: "/broadcasting/auth",
     namespace:'App.Notifications',

     });
```

resource/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

 window.Vue = require('vue');


 Vue.component('notifications', require('./components/Notifications.vue').default);





 window.onload = function () {
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

   });
   }
```

I have checked all my code and not found any other mistake, please suggest any solution for this, if I uncomment js/app.js and comment public folder jQuery, then  all other libraries gives errors like they doesn't have jQuery with them. i have also tried defer in app.js script link.

If use public folder jquery like i have shown below then all my jquery functions works and also tinymce but then i am unable to use that vue.js component

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use jQuery AND vue in the same project?

Comment: For example https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse

Comment: May be this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646206/14550771

Answer (score 1):

You have to reformat your code.
Jquery script line should be before the app.js line Eg.

```
<script src="{{asset('Assets/bootstrap4/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}" ></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```